# My character is always grounded for some reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my character to perform jumping animations only when it is grounded. For some reason, isGrounded is returning false. What do I do to make it return true?

I have used Debug.Log to find out that my code is returning IsGrounded as false, but I don't know what to do to make it true when my player's Circle colliders touch the ground.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewPlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Rigidbody2D myRigidBody;
    private Animator anim;
    private SpriteRenderer sr;

    private bool facingRight;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform[] groundPoints;

    [SerializeField]
    private float groundRadius;

    [SerializeField]
    private LayerMask whatIsGround;

    [SerializeField]
    private float movementSpeed;

    private bool isGrounded;

    private bool jump;

    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpForce;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject bullet;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        myRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();


    }
     void Update()
    {
        HandleInput();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        isGrounded = IsGrounded();
        Debug.Log(isGrounded);
        HandleMovement(horizontal);

        Flip(horizontal);

        HandleLayers();

        ResetValues();
    }

    private void HandleInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            jump = true;

        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
        {
            ShootBullet(0);
        }

    }

    private void HandleMovement(float horizontal)
    {
        if (myRigidBody.velocity.y < 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("Land", true);

        }

        myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * movementSpeed, myRigidBody.velocity.y);
        anim.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontal));

        if(isGrounded && jump)
        {

            isGrounded = false;

            myRigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));

            anim.SetTrigger("Jump"); 

        }

    }
    private void Flip(float horizontal)
    {
        if(horizontal > 0 && !facingRight || horizontal <0 && facingRight)
        {
            facingRight = !facingRight;
            Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
            theScale.x *= -1;
            transform.localScale = theScale;
        }
    }
    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        if (myRigidBody.velocity.y <= 0)
        {
            foreach (Transform point in groundPoints)
            {
                Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(point.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
                for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
                    {
                        anim.ResetTrigger("Jump");
                        anim.SetBool("Land", false);
                        return true;


                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;

    } 

    private void ResetValues()
    {
        jump = false;
    }
    public void ShootBullet(int value)
    {
        if (facingRight)
        {
            GameObject tmp = (GameObject)Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,0,-90)));
            tmp.GetComponent<BulletBehaviour>().Initialize(Vector2.right);
        }
        else
        {
            GameObject tmp = (GameObject)Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 90)));
            tmp.GetComponent<BulletBehaviour>().Initialize(Vector2.left);
        }
    }
    private void HandleLayers()
    {
        if (!isGrounded)
        {
            anim.SetLayerWeight(1, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetLayerWeight(1, 0);

        }
    }
}
```

I want my code to return isGrounded as true when my player is touching the ground. The code returns false for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Really silly mistake. I just had to tweak the ground and box colliders a little. I also had to change the layer of the ground to the right one so that "whatIsGround" would let my Circle colliders detect the ground

Comment: I made a platformer of my own using similar code if you want to take a look at it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTJqtJgATR8 There's a link in the description if you want to download the project files.